# In MySQL, is it ok to update the information_schema.COLUMNS table to set COLUMN_DEFAULT and/or IS_NULLABLE instead of using ALTER TABLE?

Tags: mysql

Is this:

```
   UPDATE information_schema.COLUMNS 
   SET 
     IS_NULLABLE = 'YES', 
     COLUMN_DEFAULT = NULL 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable'
```

An acceptable substitute for this?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn varchar(255) null;
```

I have a lot of columns spread out over a lot of tables and I would like to update them quickly to allow all non-essential data points in the application to allow null.

Comment: You can’t. The `Information_schemas views are read-only. You _have_to use a `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/140551/how-to-update-information-schema-tables-in-mysql